# awk-1-liner to sum numbers in stdin, while printing number of occurrences of certain text along with other arbritrary text

Tags: awk

I'm definitely interested in getting a book on awk. I've been won over, despite playing with it for little time. However, in the mean time, I have a problem I suspect I could solve exclusively with [g]awk. To demonstrate, I'll use some fdisk output. In this example, the desired end result would be something like:

```
Disks: 2 [240 GB total]
sda=120 GB
sdb=120 GB
```

Here's what I have:

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Disk \/dev\/[vsh]d./ {bytes+=$5} END {print "Disks: "NR" ["; gb=bytes/1024/1024/1024; print gb" GB total]"}'
```

My NR apparently prints out 73.. on my laptop with two hard drives, anyway. This, I do not understand. So far, well.. I'm maybe half-way there. Any tips or succinct tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

---

After two major excellent answers, I ended up with the following:

```
echo DISKS: $(fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ '/^Disk \/dev\/[vsh]d.|^Disk \/dev\/xvd./{print$3}' | awk '{d++;bytes+=$4;disk[$1]=$2" "$3}END{gb=bytes/1024/1024/1024; printf gb" GB total, "d" disks\n";for (i in disk) print "  "i,disk[i]}' | sed -e "s/,$/ /" -e "s/: / /")
```

Which gave me output like this:

```
DISKS: 78.3585 GB total, 2 disks
  sda 80.0 GB
  sdb 4110 MB
```

Looking forward to the day I can do that all in one awk command with no sed. :) But for now, thanks folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Disk \/dev\/[vsh]d./{d++;bytes+=$5;disk[$2]=$3$4} END {printf "Disks: "d" ["; gb=bytes/1024/1024/1024; printf gb" GB total]\n";for (i in disk) print i,disk[i]}'
Disks: 1 [93.1604 GB total]
/dev/sda: 100.0GB,
```

Comment: I appreciate it ghostdog74! Your example was just what I was looking for. It opens up some new possibilities with awk.

Answer (score 1):

You're more than half way.  The only issue is that `NR` is the number of rows (so far), not the number of rows matching your expression.  So just use another variable for that.

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Disk \/dev\/[vsh]d./ {bytes+=$5; disks+=1} END {print "Disks: "disks" ["; gb=bytes/1024/1024/1024; print gb" GB total]"}'
```

That gives:

```
Disks: x [
yyy GB total]
```

To remove the newline, and add output for each drive, try:

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Disk \/dev\/[vsh]d./ {cur_bytes=$5; bytes+=cur_bytes; disks+=1; gsub(/dev|:|\//, "", $2); print $2 "=" cur_bytes/1024/1024/1024 " GB";} END {printf "Disks: "disks" ["; gb=bytes/1024/1024/1024; print gb" GB total]"}'
```

That gives:

```
sda=xx GB
sdb=yy GB
sdc=zz GB
Disks: 3 [ww GB total]
```

It doesn't print the header first.  You could use concatenation to do that.

Comment: Or to simplify the last part: `END {print "Disks: " disks " [" gb=bytes/1024/1024/1024 " GB total]"}'`. The only reason I can see using a variable is if you wanted to move the calculation before the `print` statement to simplify its appearance. Even then, you would only need one `print`. `END {gb = bytes/1024/1024/1024; print "Disks: " disks " [" gb " GB total]"}'`

Comment: @Dennis, that's fine, except you have to remove `gb=` from the first one.

Comment: Dennis: Thanks for responding so quickly when I posted this! I've been very busy for the last week, but I saw the answers immediately. Twas very helpful.